# Unable to simulate keystrokes in macOS Mojave app

Tags: swift, macos-mojave, keystroke

I need to simulate user keyboard input (e.g., typing the letter 'a') in a macOS Mojave app (Xcode 10.3). I'm trying to use the code posted in this question:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647443/simulate-keystrokes-with-quartz-events-in-macos-sierra`

However, after my app requests permission to control System Events and I run the block of code below, nothing happens (aside from a statement printing that lets me know the block of code is actually being executed). The code runs without any errors, but I get no functionality.

I've made sure my app is not sandboxed, and my app has permission to control my computer and to control System Events (in security and privacy).

Here is the code I am using (99% of it came from the post linked above):

```
let eventSource = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)
let key: CGKeyCode = 0     // virtual key for 'a'
let eventDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: eventSource, virtualKey: key, keyDown: true)
let eventUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: eventSource, virtualKey: key, keyDown: false)
let location = CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap
eventDown?.post(tap: location)
eventUp?.post(tap: location)
```

Any ideas why this isn't working for me?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with mojave( xcode 10.3). Did you find any solution?

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: I found a solution. I will post it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add "Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description" in info.plist
2. Whenever you make any changes to your code you have to again disable and enable the permission of your app on security and privacy -> Accessibility

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! For anyone reading this later, what I put into info.plist was this (opened it as source code): `<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>`