# Cross-platform implementation of SendKeys in C#?

Tags: c#, linux, macos, cross-platform, sendkeys

I need to automate desktop applications (not a web browser) testing on Windows, Mac and Linux. On Windows I use SendKeys, what do I use on Mac and Linux? Are there any cross-platform .NET Core SendKeys implementation that I can preferably use from xUnit?

Comment: Have you found any way to mock keyinputs on linux?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the the mono/.net core SendKeys class for cross platform.

Linux native - [xdotool](http://xmodulo.com/simulate-key-press-mouse-movement-linux.html)
Mac native - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-os-x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484330/simulate-keypress-using-swift).

Comment: Thank you Jason. Using SendKeys from .NET Core or .NET Standard would be a perfect solution. However as far as I understand SendKeys is not available in .NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.7.1), as well as entire System.Windows.Forms namespace. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you are asking for makes sense.

.Net Core only has a subset of APIs in order to provide cross-platform functionality. i.e. shared libraries that will work on different platforms.

By definition this cannot include any platform-specific functionality and things like SendKeys or displaying message boxes (System.Windows.Forms) ARE platform-specific (even WPF and WinForms have different APIs for this).

> Is there a .NET Core SendKeys implementation that I can preferably use from xUnit?

I think this is what is confusing *me* about your question. Unless you're using Selenium or a fat client test tool like SikuliX, EggPlant, HP Functional you don't actually write *unit* tests for the GUI.

These are often referred to as Integration, System or GUI tests.

Both Selenium & SikuliX are free and will run cross-platform. They can be used to Send Keys. Since you're not interested in Web, SikuliX is what you want.

**Overview of SikuliX:**

https://www.scribd.com/document/87620043/sikuliscript-Overview-by-student

**Training Videos:**

SikuliX Tutorial #1 - Intro & Setup
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdCOg1bCmGo

SikuliX Tutorial #2 - The Basics
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-UYoezac4Q

SikuliX Tutorial #3 - Conditional Automation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuqfDdPlI88

SikuliX Tutorial #4 - Conditional Looping
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb513yh6RGE

SikuliX Tutorial #5 - Game Example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTTIikzxFfc&t=816s

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a library that does exactly this.

https://github.com/lucassklp/Desktop.Robot