# How to simulate a key press in NSTouchBar with NSButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard, nsbutton, nstouchbar

Looking to add functionality to an NSButton, which when clicked, performs the same keystrokes as Command + "B". Have tried setting the NSButton.keyequivalent as well as NSButton.performKeyEquivalent, but with this case, I cannot find an event to handle an NSButton press.

```
// Mute Button Pressed
@IBAction func mutePressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
    //performKeyEquivalent(with: NSButton)
    muteButton.keyEquivalent = NX_MODIFIERKEY_COMMAND
}
```

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: Edited original post, set up an IBAction to handle the NSButton being pressed, but the key equivalents do not work. Cannot figure out why...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate keypress using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484330/simulate-keypress-using-swift)

Comment: Unfortunately not, Im assuming that its an older version of swift, those methods don't even show up in swift for me.