# The code for Simulating key press doesn't work, am I missing something here?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to simulate the cmd+v to paste the string that I copied over.
I used the following code to simulate:

```
#define KEY_CODE_x ((CGKeyCode)7)
#define KEY_CODE_c ((CGKeyCode)8)
#define KEY_CODE_v ((CGKeyCode)9)

void PostCommandAndKey(CGKeyCode keyCode)
{    
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, keyCode, YES);
    CGEventRef eventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, keyCode, NO);

    CGEventSetFlags(eventDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventUp);

    CFRelease(eventUp);
    CFRelease(eventDown);
    CFRelease(source);
}
```

I am calling the above method like this:

```
- (void) pasteClicked:(id)sender{
    
    NSButton *button = (NSButton *)sender;
    PasteItem *pi = self.pasteItems[button.tag];
    
    [self.pasteBoard setString:pi.text forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
    
    NSString * str = [self.pasteBoard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];

    NSLog(@"pasting %@", str);
    
    PostCommandAndKey(KEY_CODE_v);
}
```

The cursor is on a `NSTextField` in the same window where the pasteClicked: button is, but I don't see any thing pasted. However the str variable get the right value as I see in the logs.

I am using OS 11.5.2.

What am I missing here?
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't even know under what class you are writing code.

Comment: @ElTomato: All the codes are in AppDelegate

Comment: Have you tried simulating key press "v" without the command key?

Comment: @Willeke: Yes, nothing happens either

Comment: Is this a permission issue?

Comment: @Willeke: what kind of permission should I give and should not give? I have non-sandboxed this app. Please suggest what else can I try.

Comment: Try setting the keyEquivalent of your button to 'v' and set the action to 'paste:'

Comment: Since this appears to be a 'simulation' you could also try adding [txtFld setStringValue:str]; to the -pasteClicked method.

Comment: Try to wait a bit between the events `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];`. Do you want to paste in your own app?

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to get your -pasteClicked: method to run on my system.  The following demo will copy a string to the clipboard then retrieve it and set it in a text field which appears to be what you are trying to accomplish.  To run in Xcode delete the main.m source code and replace it with the following.  Also delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate to avoid duplicate symbols.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
 NSWindow *window;
 NSTextField *txtFld;
}
 -(void) pasteClicked: (id)sender;
 -(void) buildMenu;
 -(void) buildWnd;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

#define KEY_CODE_x ((CGKeyCode)7)
#define KEY_CODE_c ((CGKeyCode)8)
#define KEY_CODE_v ((CGKeyCode)9)

void PostCommandAndKey(CGKeyCode keyCode) {
 NSLog(@"keyCode: %hu", keyCode);
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, keyCode, YES);
    CGEventRef eventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, keyCode, NO);

    CGEventSetFlags(eventDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventUp);

    CFRelease(eventUp);
    CFRelease(eventDown);
    CFRelease(source);
}

- (void) pasteClicked:(id)sender{
NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *strToCopy = @"My text to be copied to clipboard.";
[pb declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSPasteboardTypeString] owner:nil];
BOOL copied = [pb setString:strToCopy forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
NSLog (@"copied = %d", copied);
NSString *string = [pb stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
[txtFld setStringValue:string];
NSLog(@"pasting \"%@\"",string);
PostCommandAndKey(KEY_CODE_v);
}

-(void) buildMenu {
// **** Menu Bar **** //
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
// **** App Menu **** //
 NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 [appMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
 [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
}

-(void) buildWnd {

 #define _wndW  500
 #define _wndH  150

 window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ) styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];

 [window center];
 [window setTitle: @"Test window"];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// **** Text Field **** //
txtFld = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, _wndH - 50, _wndW - 60, 20 )];
[txtFld setEditable:YES];
[[window contentView] addSubview:txtFld];

 // **** Paste Button **** //
 NSButton *pasteBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 60, _wndH - 100, 95, 30 )];
 [pasteBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
 [pasteBtn setTitle: @"Paste"];
 [pasteBtn setAction: @selector (pasteClicked:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: pasteBtn];

 // **** Quit btn **** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

-(void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 [self buildMenu];
 [self buildWnd];
}

-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
}
@end

int main () {
 NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
 [application setDelegate:appDelegate];
 [application run];
 return 0;
}
```