# How can i create an keyboard button press event programmatically OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to create an remote ios app. So if i press any key like up arrow in ios device. Then how can i fire same event of key board in Mac os.  I am rrecive data in mac through wifi using bonjour. But the problem is can not create the event. Try to learn Quartz Event Services. But did not get Any sample.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, Keyboard events are managed by Cocoa and Carbon, not Quartz.

Comment: @Xvolks Can You Give some example?

Comment: This has already been answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734349/simulate-keypress-for-system-wide-hotkeys