# Cocoa: get and change text and selection in third-party apps (without simulating key presses nor using accessibility API)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a Mac utility app in which I would like to manipulate text and selection in third-party apps. I found two methods for doing so:

- [Simulating key presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734349/simulate-keypress-for-system-wide-hotkeys)
- [Using the accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/index.html)

However, they both have major drawbacks and I'm wondering if there are any other methods I could explore?

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what services are for – see [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000850-BCIDHJJA). In a nutshell, you make an app and register it as a service provider. You advertise your service using `Info.plist` where you specify `NSStringPboardType` as both the sender and return type. The user will then be able to right-click on a text selection in any app and choose your service from the popup menu.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked services. Unfortunately, they don't allow any selection manipulation and I can't find a way to programmatically trigger one with the user's selection (as part of a larger suite of actions or even just to configure a keyboard shortcut in my app instead of the system preferences one).